# Audio use js to use image for playpause btn

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to js so forgive me. I'm using the html5 audio tag with some js to only show play and pause as a button. I would like to change the text for play & pause out with images. Like playbtn.png and pausebtn.png. Here is where I'm stuck.

html:::

```
   <!-- hidden audio player -->
<audio id="audio" controls autoplay hidden="">
    <source src="music/eatForTwo.wav" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="music/eatForTwo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <p>Your Browser Doesn't Support The HTML5 audio Element</p>
</audio>

<button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()" ><img id="imgbtn" src="music/pausebtn.png"/></button>
<!-- javascript for audio control
-->
<script src="code/html5audio.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

js:::

```
 // Grab a handle to the video
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   // Turn off the default controls
   audio.controls = false;

function togglePlayPause() {
var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
if (audio.paused || audio.ended) {
  playpause.title = "pause";
  playpause.style.backgroundImage = "url(music\pausebtn.png)";
  audio.play();
}
else {
  playpause.title = "play";
  playpause.style.backgroundImage = "url(music\playbtn.png)";
  audio.pause();
}
}
```

Comment: You already have button? And you want to use image on button instead of text?

Comment: The text buttons were the original setup. I would like to have 2 button images playbtn.png/pausebtn.png instead of the text changing. I'm really new to programing - (info assurance by trade). sudo code class once many moons ago - so all help is appreciated!

Comment: `<button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()"><img  id="imgbtn" src="music/pausebtn.png"/></button>` this is your code or original?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your js as following but you have to change `url(c:\folder\img.jpg)` to `url(yourPath)` ....  Now yourPath does not mean yourPath it means the location of the image on your hard disk

```
 // Grab a handle to the video
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   // Turn off the default controls
   audio.controls = false;

function togglePlayPause() {
var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
if (audio.paused || audio.ended) {
  //playpause.title = "pause";
  playpause.style.backgroundImage = "url(c:\folder\img.jpg)";
  audio.play();
}
else {
  //playpause.title = "play";
  playpause.style.backgroundImage = "url(c:\img1.jpg)";
  audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: @user1790191 See edited answer. I just changed few lines from your js. you can compare yours and mine. i am still there. try to Be quick in response :)

Comment: @user1790191 Actually new users are depreciated on SO. It s the policy perhaps.  They are ignored because they are usually unable to get what is being told and their questions on the other hand usually do not cause much upvotes. But for me they deserve most. You know I am taking time voluntarily. Actually its facebook for me :) Is your problem still standing?

Comment: @user1790191 change `<button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()" ><img id="imgbtn" src="music/pausebtn.png"/></button>` to `<button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()" />` and tell me the result.

Delete all of your comments under this answer otherwise you may not be allowed to comment more.